# cast void type pointer in an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void

Suppose I have an Uint array: `Uint myarray[10]`. `Uint` is unsigned 16 bit integer.
I also define an `void` type pointer such that

```
void * arrayHandle = &myarray;
```

Add some offset such that `arrayHandle` points to `myarray[3]`(mark here, will change offset in another test)

```
arrayHandle = (Uint *)arrayHandle + 3;
```

Then assign a 32 bit float type data to memory where `arrayHandle` points to

```
*((float *)arrayHandle) = 1234.5678;
```

32 bit 1234.5678 can be expressed as two 16 bit Uint raw data, where the higher 16 bit in decimal is 21035, and the lower 16 bit in decimal is 17562.

After all, I go to check the array and find `myarray[2] = 21035` and `myarray[3] = 17562`.

However, when I go back to change the offset such that `arrayHandle` points to `myarray[2]`

```
arrayHandle = (Uint *)arrayHandle + 2;
```

And do the similar float assignment. I find that `myarray[2] = 21035` and `myarray[3] = 17562`.

The array content is exactly the same! Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: BTW, what are you going to do? maybe you can use union?

Comment: You are aware that `&myarray` does *not* evaluate to an pointer of type `Uint*`, *but* to a pointer of type `Uint (*)[10]`, aren't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then assign a 32 bit float type data to memory where arrayHandle
>   points to
>
> ```
> *((float *)arrayHandle) = 1234.5678;
> ```

Stop here, you are actually breaking *strict aliasing rule*, thus yielding an UB (so anything can happen). Even if `arrayHandle` is of type `void *`, it originates from `myarray`, that is declared as unsigned integer type.

Use array of unions for [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union) between integer and floating-point types.

Comment: `*((float *)arrayHandle)` may also break alignment requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Array is already a pointer, try to use `void * arrayHandle = myarray`;

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, they *decay into* pointers for most operations.

Comment: Yes, if you try printing `&myarray` and `myarray` you will get the very same address.